# Rename a field in Mongodb collection using Spring data and Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I have a collection with several fields and would like to update both the field name through Java program. For example

```
{_id : ObjectId(xxxxxxxxxxxx), field1: "value1", field2  : "value2"}
```

Now I have a requirement to rename the field1 to say field11. How do I do it using Spring Data.

Basically this ops using Java
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-update-multiple-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-using-java

Comment: thanks.. this might be useful to update the value.. but I am looking to update the fieldName.. in this case "city" to say "town"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

void renameFunction() {
    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    updateQuery.append("$rename",new BasicDBObject().append("field1", "field11").append("field2", "field22"));  
 mongoTemplate.getCollection("Collection_Name").updateMany(searchQuery,updateQuery);
         }
```

Comment: this seems relevant to my need.. let me try

Comment: thanks for this.. cn you also tell me what's the best way to get a confirmation that update was successful? Should  wasacknowledged be used at the end of updatemany?

Comment: no it wont give you any confirmation on the update, it just will let you check if no failover or crash occurred. instead you can utilise `if (updateResult.getMatchedCount() > 0)` then `updateResult.getModifiedCount()  must be >  0`  . `updateMany` returns `com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult` object.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `searchQuery` object used for ? As far as I can see its just an empty BSON object.

Comment: searchQuery is a BSON object which can be used to select the documents which needs to be updated. an empty BSON object means it will select all the documents of that collection. for a more robust solution we can make the searchQuery object like
`{ $or: [ { "field1" :  { $exists :  true } },{ "field2" : { $exists :  true }} ] } `

this will select those document only which will have either field1 or field2

while
`{}`

this will select all documents